# Actionlink doesn't post Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, actionlink

I am new to ASP.net and MVC so forgive me if this seems like a silly question.

I have the following Actionlink:

```
<span>@Html.ActionLink(item.MetadataDocumentSetId.ToString(), "ShowDocumentMetadata", new { controller = "Metadata", id = item.MetadataDocumentSetId })</span>
```

I also have this (currently commented out):

```
<span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.MetadataDocumentSetId, new { style = "display:inline"})</span>
```

When I use the textbox, the ID will post, but not when I use that actionlink.  How can I get the actionlink to post the Id?

Again, I am new to this so forgive me if I am not explaining it all too well.

Answer (score 1):

`ActionLink` doesn't post values, if you mean by post that you want to load a page based on the id you shoud do this (this is a GET, not a POST):

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetById(string id)
    {
      var currentId = id;

      // do something with currentId

      return this.View()
    }
```

ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "GetById", "MyController", new { id = "12-34"}, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong overload of `Html.ActionLink`, try this instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.MetadataDocumentSetId.ToString(), "ShowDocumentMetaData", 
        "Metadata", new { id = item.MetadataDocumentSetId }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title","Action", "Controller", new { id = item.MetadataDocumentSetId  }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<span>@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "ShowDocumentMetadata", "Metadata", new { id = item.MetadataDocumentSetId.ToString()}, null)</span>
```

You're selecting the wrong ActionLink method. For more info - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions_methods(v=vs.118).aspx

But you want to pass the parameter through in RouteValues